# How to remove" Warning as Error: the is field xxxxx is never used" from Asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2017, web-config

I am facing an issue while compiling my Asp.net WebSite( not application) written in C#.

[image]

How to resolve these errors?

Comment: You have multiple warnings about fields you are not using.  So, you could use those fields or you could remove them from the classes in which they are not used.  Read this about why those warnings have been elevated to errors (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/errors-warnings).  It's a compiler setting that I'm assuming you set

Comment: Generally, you should listen to warnings as they are trying to tell you something, in this case that the fields you have declared are not being used (but are still taking up memory), so that you should consider removing them. There is also a compiler setting about treating warnings as errors which you could turn off.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve the problem, you can refer to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0169).

“CS0169” means a private variable was declared but never referenced, you should consider removing the variable declaration.